# when product of irrational numbers = rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

let $a$ and $b$ be irrational numbers. when do we have $ a \cdot b $ = rational number?

for example $\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}=2$. I was wondering if there some conditions for the product to be a rational number.

Comment: The irrationals have very, very little structure. Take an irrational $x$, then $\frac{1}{x}$ is irrational, but $x\cdot\frac{1}{x} = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps the most honest answer to this question is "sometimes" ...

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks for your comments. are there necessary conditions?

Comment: hint : $\sqrt{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$, so yes $\sqrt{2} \ \  . \ \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ has good chances to be an integer

Comment: The only time you have xy =q rational is iff a=qx1/b for some rational q. That's a very specific, valid, wellwdefined and workable condition.

Comment: You may observe that if $a$ is irrational and $a\cdot b$ is rational, then $b$ _has to be irrational_ (if it is nonzero); so making that an additional hypothesis is not of much help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're hoping for in terms of an answer, but: exactly when one is a rational multiple of the other's reciprocal!

Ex: $\sqrt{2}\times {3\over \sqrt{2}}$ is rational, but $\sqrt{2}\times{\pi\over\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational.

You might find this unsatisfying - unfortunately, I'm not really sure a satisfying characterization exists!

---

A somewhat abstract necessary condition can be stated using the language of fields: $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\mathbb{Q}(y)$. However, this is definitely not sufficient, since e.g. $\pi^2$ isn't rational.

Comment: I (shamefully) had to think twice about whether $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational multiple of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$!

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational because otherwise $\pi^2 = \frac{2m^2}{n^2}$ contradicting the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental. This wasn't immediately obvious to me, so I just thought I'd mention it :)

Answer (score 17):

For each irrational number, **a**, there exists a countably infinite number of irrational numbers, **b**, such that **a ⋅ b** is rational.  These numbers are exactly the rational numbers except zero divided by **a**.  Call this set **B**.

PROOF -- SUFFICIENT

Let **q** be a rational number other than zero.  Then **b = q / a** is irrational.  However, **a * b** equals **a * q / a** which is just **q**, a rational number.  Therefore, every number in **B** is an irrational that produces a rational number when multiplied by **a**.

PROOF -- NECESSARY

Consider an irrational number, **b**, which, when multiplied by **a**, produces a rational number.  Call the result **q**.  Then **b = q / a**.  But **q** is rational so **q / a** is in set **B**.

Q.E.D.

Comment: You can strengthen the statement by introducing the set **B** just after you mention **a**, and then stating that **B** is countably infinite and dense in the reals. Besides the dense part, note also that your formulation seems to allow for the possibility that an uncountable set of irrational numbers **b** exists for each **a**, with the part about "These numbers are exactly the . . ." only referring to the previously mentioned countably infinite set of irrational numbers.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

> $ab$ is rational iff either of $a,b$ is zero or the ratio $a+b : \frac1a+\frac1b$ is rational, for any reals $a,b$.

No products in sight! Heheh...

Comment: Also $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\in\mathbb Q$ ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I thought of that too but didn't include it because the square is too much a product. =)

Comment: You can also evaluate those squares by prostaphaeresis.

Answer (score 3):

A bit too large for a comment..

For the subset of irrationals being $n$-th roots of rationals:

For (all) primes $p_i$ : consider the numbers being on the form $$q = \prod_{\forall i} {p_i}^{q_i}$$Any root of a rational number could be uniquely represented as $q_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ and then iff the sum of $q_i$ for two numbers $\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$ then their product should be a rational number.

$q_i$ being a negative integer would mean the denominator has a positive power of prime $p_i$ in it's representation and positive would mean the same for numerator.

---

However there are of course very many irrationals except for the integer roots of rationals so this only expresses a method for a very tiny subset of irrational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be a condition on one of the numbers alone, as for any irrational real $a$, there is at least one $b$ that fits (just take $b=\frac1a$).

Now the necessary and sufficient condition for a pair of numbers is... $a\cdot b\in\mathbb Q$.

You can weaken to get a necessary but not sufficient condition such as $a^2\cdot b^2\in\mathbb Q$.

You can strengthen to get a sufficient but not necessary condition such as $a\cdot b\in\mathbb N$.

This is not of much use.

A vaguely interesting condition is that $a$ and $b$ must be both transcendental or algebraic.

Comment: Note that $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be irrational . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any irrational number a (obviously a ≠ 0), and any rational number q ≠ 0, then let b = q / a. b will be irrational. And the pairs (a, b) that you can create this way are exactly all pairs of irrational numbers with a rational product.